# Disable subtypes on hybris create-wizard

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am configuring a create-wizard for media (only media, no subtypes), that is called from the reference editor(the editor has search disabled). I do not need the option to select the subtypes of media during item creation. Eg I have a `DocumentModel extends MediaModel` and I do not want to show the option to create Document model. Editor area config:

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="productDocuments">
        <editorArea:editor-parameter>
          <editorArea:name>createOnly</editorArea:name>
          <editorArea:value>true</editorArea:value>
</editorArea:editor-parameter>
```

I want only create Media option to be shown and not any other subtypes.Image given here shows the config now and I want to remove everything except MediaModel which is the supertype of all the other types shown below it.
[image]

What additonal configuration to the above is required so as to restrict the creation to only Media model and not the DocumentModel?

Answer (score 0):

From help.hybris.com docs,

You can configure the editor using the `custom-attributes` element in the ZUL file of your widget. It applies to any reference editor in your ZUL / config file. The following attributes are supported:

**restrictToType** :
Restrict the items displayed on the selection list to a given type and its subtypes.

```
<editor id="multiReferenceEditor" type="MultiReference-LIST(Product)">
    <custom-attributes pageSize="5" />
</editor>
```

Its applicable multiple places and editors.

Source: help.hybris.com